# Purvey or Provide?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I've seen a new word to me in an interview. To purvey.

Well I understand the meaning. But what's the distinction then between provide and purvey?
This question seems to be not popular, as I haven't been able to find anything.

The original sentence says, "What is the audience experiencing **in purveying** the work that actors present?"

I hope someone will enlighten me about the difference of the meaning.

Comment: Perhaps a typo for surveying?

Comment: @Anton, that's definitely correct. I was watching an interview on youtube with subtitles. So it's kinda double checked.

Comment: Glad about that. As an afterthought, in Britain, *purvey* as an alternative to *sell* or *provide* has overtones of superiority. Whereas *peddle* has overtones of lowness. Companies purvey goods to the Queen. Shady dealers peddle trash to the gullible.

Comment: *The original sentence says, "What is the audience experiencing in purveying the work that actors present?"* This makes no sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a typo or malapropism

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purveys%2Csurveys&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurveys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveys%3B%2Cc0), the derived noun ***purveyors*** (upmarket term for ***providers = merchants** who sell something*) isn't quite as common as ***surveyors*** (land / property inspectors), but at least it's in the same street.

Comment: On the other hand, the actual verb form *[he] **purveys** [fine wines]* is [***virtually unknown***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purveys%2Csurveys&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurveys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveys%3B%2Cc0) by comparison with *[he] **surveys** [buildings]*.

Comment: I don't know if the OP's example is a typo, but the examples I found show this meaning is used.

Answer (score 0):

**purvey**

> (transitive) To procure; to get.
>
> Sir Walter Scott *I mean to purvey me a wife after the fashion of the children of Benjamin.* [wordsense](https://www.wordsense.eu/purveyed/)

> transitive verb To procure; to get. [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/purvey) ("from the GNU
> version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English.")

*Purvey* is evidently used with its meaning of **procure** (as a purveyor needs to do in order to sell) figuratively extended to mean something in the rage of *take in/absorb/examine/survey* a subject, a field, the past, etc.

---

> Once their datedness is widely enjoyed, such locales lose their
> authenticity and become period stage sets: 'Primitive' places where
> one could formerly step back in time now **purvey the past**
> self-consciously. [David Lowenthal; *The Past is a Foreign
> Country*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Past_is_a_Foreign_Country/jMqsAQZmv5IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20past%22&pg=PA50&printsec=frontcover) (1985)

> Those who **purvey the past to the present** therefore perform a
> highly sensitive function and bear a profound responsibility. Not
> quite priests, perhaps. But Very Important People nonetheless. [Donald
> A. Yerxa; *Recent Themes on Historians and the Public*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Recent_Themes_on_Historians_and_the_Publ/yS0McDWd2fcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20past%22&pg=PA26&printsec=frontcover)

> When we **purvey the literature** on feasting, there are a number of
> frequently occurring kinds of explanations that address the question
> of why feasting tends to be so lavish
> [Brian Hayden; *The Power of Feasts*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Power_of_Feasts/gLhUBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=When%20we%20purvey%20the%20literature%20on%20feasting,%20there%20are%20a%20number%20of%20frequently%20occurring%20kinds%20of%20explanations%20that%20address%20the%20question%20of%20why%20feasting%20tends%20to%20be%20so%20lavish&pg=PA52&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> But neither he nor his ante bellum successors diverted the college
> from its inceptive aim to **purvey the literature** culture of gentlemen.
> [W. F. Guess; *South Carolina*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22But%20neither%20he%20nor%20his%20ante%20bellum%20successors%20diverted%20the%20college%20from%20its%20inceptive%20aim%20to%20purvey%20the%20literature%20culture%20of%20gentlemen%20%22) (1960)

> In many respects this book is intended to be an antidote to the
> complication and extreme mathematical models that **purvey the field**
> of investment management these days. [Murray Gunn; *Trading Regime
> Analysis*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trading_Regime_Analysis/Ii2_PWWlbycC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20field%22&pg=PR11&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> Hence, she showed high network acuity, the ability to **purvey the
> field** and identify who shows good fit and adds complementary value
> to her existing network. [Y. W. Park and Y. J. Park; *Corporate Social
> Responsibility and Entrepreneurship for Sustainability*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Corporate_Social_Responsibility_and_Entr/1_05EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20field%22&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> As we **purvey the landscape** of our theological past, we question
> what we see there that might be useful to us now, or what might be a
> decorative touch to the theological home we are construction for
> ourselves, and what we wish to leave behind. [Ralph McMichael; *The
> Eucharistic Faith*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Eucharistic_Faith/E3C9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20landscape%22&pg=PT74&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> My partner, Martin Reymert, and I saw the need to not just **purvey
> the works** in New York but to catalogue and exhibit them in order to
> build a critical foundation for collecting academic nineteenth-century
> art. [C. E. Foster et al.; *French Master Drawings from the Collection
> of Muriel Butkin*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/French_Master_Drawings_from_the_Collecti/WXefo1LICqgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20works%22&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> We do not offer color photography, we do not offer discussions of
> current events, we cannot afford to **purvey the works** of writers
> whose names are familiar to most... [*The Texas Review*, Vol. 5,
> p.109](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Texas_Review/ZbZAAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22purvey%20the%20works%22&dq=%22purvey%20the%20works%22&printsec=frontcover) (1984, snippet view)

> Without imagination (and intuition), real science is impossible. ...
> Imagination goes one step further. ... It is to take off on a flight
> of fancy to **purvey the entire universe in your mind's eye**.
> ["Liberating Science and Imagination" in *Science in Society*, 57,
> Spring 2013](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_in_Society_57/rT9eAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22purvey%20the%20entire%22&pg=PA38&printsec=frontcover)

*Purvey* in this last example is effectively *to contemplate*.

Answer (score -1):

Well in many cases purvey has more a connotation of selling, or seeking to desseminate. But its use in this sentence makes me wonder if it isn't being used in its historical obsolete sense of "foreseeing" or "preparing for" (see [reference](https://www.wordnik.com/words/purvey). I wonder if broader context world be helpful, because I don't understand what this sentence is trying to communicate.

Answer (score -1):

**Purvey** has a more traditional feel to it as in

**John Smith and Co, purveyors of fine foods**